# Find n's for which $P_n$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the numbers $P_n=(3^n-1)/2$. Find $n$'s for which $P_n$ is prime.

Conjecture: If $n \equiv 1 \mod 6$, and $n$ is prime, then $P_n$ is prime.

I have tried proving this by contradiction but it seems unnatural. And I tried it by induction and I got stuck proving the n+1 case.

Comment: Rather than try proving it, try disproving it.

Comment: $19\equiv 1\pmod 6$ and $19$ is prime, but
$(3^{19}-1)/2 = 581130733 = 1597\cdot 363889$
is not prime.

Comment: See if you can prove that when $P_n$ is prime, then $n$ is prime. That seems more likely, and is what happens with Mersenne primes.

Comment: [This sequence](http://oeis.org/A028491) in OEIS shows a few initial terms. A simple modular condition is unlikely and possibly even provably insufficient to determine the primality of $P_n$.